# Ooops... AttributeError when clearing failed task state in airflow

Tags: airflow

I am trying to clear a failed task so that it will run again.

I usually do this with the web GUI from the tree view

[image: tree view showing failed task & clear popup]

After selecting "Clear" I am directed to an error page:

[image: error page]

The traceback on this page is the same error I receive when trying to clear this task using the CLI:

```
[u@airflow01 ~]# airflow clear -s 2002-07-29T20:25:00 -t 
coverage_check  gom_modis_aqua_coverage_check 
[2018-01-16 16:21:04,235] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-01-16 16:21:05,192] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /root/airflow/dags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 612, in clear
    include_upstream=args.upstream,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 3173, in sub_dag
    dag = copy.deepcopy(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 166, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 3159, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 246, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 166, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 2202, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 246, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/copy.py", line 309, in _reconstruct
    y.__dict__.update(state)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Looking for ideas on what may have caused this, what I should do to fix this task, and how to avoid this in the future.

I was able to work around the issue by deleting the task record using the "Browse > Task Instances" search, but would still like to explore the issue as I have seen this multiple times.

Although my DAG code is getting complicated, here is an excerpt from where the operator is defined within the dag:

```
    trigger_granule_dag_id = 'trigger_' + process_pass_dag_name
    coverage_check = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='coverage_check',
        python_callable=_coverage_check,
        provide_context=True,
        retries=10,
        retry_delay=timedelta(hours=3),
        queue=QUEUE.PYCMR,
        op_kwargs={
            'roi':region,
            'success_branch_id': trigger_granule_dag_id
        }
    )
```

The full source code can be browsed at [github/USF-IMARS/imars_dags](https://github.com/USF-IMARS/imars_dags). Here are links to the most relevant parts:

- Operator instantiated in [/gom/gom_modis_aqua_coverage_check.py](https://github.com/USF-IMARS/imars_dags/blob/master/dags/gom/gom_modis_aqua_coverage_check.py#L21) using modis_aqua_coverage_check factory
- factory function defines coverage_check BranchPythonOperator in [/builders/modis_aqua_coverage_check.py](https://github.com/USF-IMARS/imars_dags/blob/master/dags/builders/modis_aqua_coverage_check.py#L50)
- python_callable is [_coverage_check function in same file](https://github.com/USF-IMARS/imars_dags/blob/master/dags/builders/modis_aqua_coverage_check.py#L139)

Comment: Can you post your DAG code as well. I faced a similar issue and was able to resolve it. I can take a look at your code and tell you the error.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @SaiKiranNeelakantam . Here is a link to the task within the DAG: https://github.com/USF-IMARS/imars_dags/blob/master/dags/builders/modis_aqua_coverage_check.py#L45-L61 . I will also add the excerpt to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a sample DAG that I created to mimic the error that you are facing.

```
import logging
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import boto3
from airflow import DAG
from airflow import configuration as conf
from airflow.operators import ShortCircuitOperator, PythonOperator, DummyOperator


def athena_data_validation(**kwargs):
    pass


start_date = datetime.now()

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': start_date,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'wait_for_downstream': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30)
}

dag_name = 'data_validation_dag'

schedule_interval = None  

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=dag_name,
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval)

athena_client = boto3.client('athena', region_name='us-west-2')

DAG_SCRIPTS_DIR = conf.get('core', 'DAGS_FOLDER') + "/data_validation/"

start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='Start_Task', dag=dag)

end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='End_Task', dag=dag)

data_validation_task = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='Data_Validation',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=athena_data_validation,
    op_kwargs={
        'athena_client': athena_client,
        'sql_file': DAG_SCRIPTS_DIR + 'data_validation.sql',
        's3_output_path': 's3://XXX/YYY/'
    },
    dag=dag)
data_validation_task.set_upstream(start_task)
data_validation_task.set_downstream(end_task)
```

After one successful run, I tried to clear the `Data_Validation` task and got the same error (see below).
[image]
[image]

I removed the `athena_client` object creation and placed it inside the `athena_data_validation` function and then it worked. So when we do a `clear` in Airflow UI, it tries to do a `deepcopy` and get all the objects from previous run. I am still trying to understand why its not able to get a copy of the `object` type but I got a workaround which was working for me.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reproduce this with a much cleaner DAG. This will make troubleshooting this issue much easier.

Answer (score 1):

During some operations, Airflow deep copies some objects. Unfortunately, some objects do not allow this. The boto client is a good example of something that does not deep copies nicely, thread objects are another, but large objects with nested references like a reference to a parent task below can also cause issues.

In general, you do not want to instantiate a client in the dag code itself. That said, I do not think that it is your issue here. Though I do not have access to the pyCMR code to see if it could be an issue.

Comment: airflow v1.8.0. 

pyCMR src I am using is available [here](https://github.com/7yl4r/pyCMR).

Can you expand on "In general, you do not want to instantiate a client in the dag code itself"? I don't quite understand.

Comment: What I mean by that is that the script with defines the DAG should in general not do any work (request files over the network etc...). This should be done inside operators.

Comment: Oh, yes that makes sense. However, my usage of pyCMR is fully contained in the `python_callable`. That counts as "inside operators", does it not?